# Run Angular in a certain path

Tags: angular

Is it possible to run Angular in for example http://localhost:4200/abcde instead instead of http://localhost:4200/? I haven't found an option to change pathname.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. Very simple with `base-href`. Angular Docs tells us it's important that you have the starting and closing **/** slashes here. Read all about it [here](https://angular.io/cli/build#arguments).

```
ng build --base-href /abcde/
```

This will set the base href in the index.html automatically, too. Here you don't need the closing **/** slash I think.

**DEV with ng `serve`**

Here you can use `--serve-path. All infos [here](https://angular.io/cli/serve).

```
ng serve --serve-path /abcde
```